# ¿Por qué no puedo asignarle a referencias números pero sí puedo asignar estos a referencias constantes?

Tags: c++

```
int& variable = 5;  //Error.
const int& variable = 5;    //Funciona.
```

Es algo que me inquieta de *C++*, entiendo el primer caso pero no por qué **no** da error en la **segunda línea**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo entiendo (aunque estoy elucubrando un poco) que una referencia a un número literal como 5 el fondo sería un "puntero" a un lugar de la memoria (sin nombre) en el que hay un 5. El problema es que si tienes más de una variable definida como `int& v=5`, entonces todas ellas apuntarían al mismo lugar, es decir "al mismo 5". O al menos un compilador podría decidir implementarlo de ese modo para mayor eficiencia en el uso de memoria.

Si el compilador permitiera algo como esto:

```
int& v1 = 5;
int& v2 = 5;
int& v3 = 5;
```

y el compilador decidiera crear en memoria un solo objeto 5, entonces todas esas variables se estarían refiriendo al mismo 5.

Sería posible que más adelante en el programa se hiciera por ejemplo `v1=8`, y entonces estarías cambiando ese 5 por un 8, por lo que de pronto todas esas variables que valían 5 (como `v2` y `v3`) pasan mágicamente a valer 8.

Eso es un peligro, y el compilador no lo permite. En el segundo caso en cambio no hay peligro pues el 5 se convierte en "inmutable" (no puedes asignarle otro valor). De modo que se pueden tener muchas variables que apunten "al mismo 5" sin peligro, y el compilador lo permite.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Le veo todo el sentido del mundo ahora.